# Limit of integral with unbounded derivative on bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let $I:=(a,b)$ be a bounded interval and $\overline{I}=[a,b]$. Assume $f\in C(\overline{I})$ with $f\geq 0$ in $\overline{I}$. Moreover, assume $f'\geq 0$ in $[a,b)$ and $\lim\limits_{t\to b}f'(t)= \infty$.

Can we deduce $\lim\limits_{x\to b^{-}}\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt=\infty$?

I have tried by using contradiction by assuming $\lim\limits_{x\to b^{-}}\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt=L<\infty$ but I dont know how to derive any contradiction from this fact. I am thinking to use mean value theorem but not sure.

Any hint or help is much appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the behavior of $f(x) =\sqrt{x}$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Then transform this function so it meets your requirements.